# Show legend that matplotlib dynamically created

Tags: python, matplotlib, scatter-plot

My df has 4 columns: x, y, z, and grouping. I have created a 3D plot, with the assigned color of each point being decided by what grouping it belongs to in that row. For reference, a "grouping" can be any number from 1 to 6. The code is shown below:

```
fig = plt.figure()
ax = Axes3D(fig)
ax.scatter3D(df.x, df.y, df.z, c=df.grouping)
plt.show()
```

I would like to show a legend on the plot that shows which color belongs to which grouping. Previously, I was using Seaborn for a 2D plot and the legend was automatically plotted. How can I add this feature with matplotlib?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the values to be colormapped are numeric, the solution can be as simple as:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D

a = np.random.rand(3,40)
c = np.random.randint(1,7, size=a.shape[1])

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection="3d")
sc = ax.scatter3D(*a, c=c)
plt.legend(*sc.legend_elements())
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: A bit more verbose of an answer than needed but definitely solved the issue for me! Assigning ```sc = ax.scatter3D(df.x, df.y, df.z, c=df.grouping)``` and then calling ```plt.legend(*sc.legend_elements())``` before plotting did the job. Thank you!

Comment: This is not "more verbose [..] than needed"! But rather the question does not contain a [mcve]!

Comment: Just realized my initial reply didn't post but you are correct. Still getting used to posting on SO. Thanks again!